# Using any 'androidNavigationBar' option in Expo app.json crashes Expo Go in Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, android-navigation-bar

I'm trying to edit the looks of the bottom navigation bar on Android using [Expo NavigationBar](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/navigation-bar/) I've installed it by running `expo install expo-navigation-bar`

For example, in my `app.json`, changing color:

```
{
    "androidNavigationBar": {
      "backgroundColor": "#188780"
    }
}
```

or making it hidden:

```
{
  "androidNavigationBar": {
    "visible": "immersive",
  }
}
```

**Using either option works, but they both cause Expo Go app on Android to crash**. Doesn't crash every time, but very often. And just removing `androidNavigationBar` from app.json fixes the crashing.

Comment: did you ever got a solution? for me it only works when developing locally but as soon as I build for release the navigation bar in android doesn't hide